# zsh: command not found: php

Tags: php, macos, macos-monterey

I have been using **php** with **mamp** on mac for a year even with old versions of MacOS, since I installed *MacOS Monterrey* if I type `php` on the terminal I get a message:`zsh: command not found: php`

Using older versions of MacOS I have never had this problem.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Seems PHP is not installed or not in the path.

Comment: My projects starts on localhost, but when I need the terminal to use for example 'php artisan serve' I get the message 'zsh: command not found: php'

Comment: same problem here too. Do anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I had the same issue after updating to Monterry. After some googling, I find out MacOS doesn't include PHP. You need Homebrew to install PHP again.

`brew install php`

https://daily-dev-tips.com/posts/installing-php-on-your-mac/

Comment: I cannot install brew following documentation... Is there anything specific to do?

Comment: Did you enter this into your terminal?
`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

https://brew.sh/

Comment: Finally it's work, really thank you!

Comment: nobody mentioned that installing both homebrew and brew are quite slow tasks, and both will download and install a lot of big files! "This will take a while!!" :D

Answer (score 121):

When I update MacOS Monterey, PHP was remove.
I found this article it useful and solve this problem for me.
https://wpbeaches.com/updating-to-php-versions-7-4-and-8-on-macos-12-monterey

Add the PHP formulae

```
brew tap shivammathur/php
```

Choose the PHP version – this example uses 7.4

```
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.4
```

Link the PHP Version

```
brew link --overwrite --force php@7.4
```

Restart the Terminal

```
php -v
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 16):

Homebrew users:

This can happen simply because your php version is not linked.

Goto /usr/local/Cellar, list out the content and see what versions of php you have installed. You should see directories and symlinks as so:

```php
lrwxr-xr-x    1 kazajhodo  admin      7 May 22  2019 php72 -> php@7.2
lrwxr-xr-x    1 kazajhodo  admin      7 Feb 26  2020 php73 -> php@7.3
lrwxr-xr-x    1 kazajhodo  admin      7 Jun 12  2020 php74 -> php@7.4
lrwxr-xr-x    1 kazajhodo  admin      7 Jan 22  2021 php80 -> php@8.0
lrwxr-xr-x    1 kazajhodo  admin      7 Jan  4 11:58 php81 -> php@8.1
drwxr-xr-x    3 kazajhodo  staff     96 Jan  4 11:34 php@7.2
drwxr-xr-x    3 kazajhodo  staff     96 Aug  8 19:32 php@7.3
drwxr-xr-x    4 kazajhodo  staff    128 Jan  4 11:55 php@7.4
lrwxr-xr-x    1 kazajhodo  admin     18 Jan 22  2021 php@8.0 -> /usr/local/bin/php
lrwxr-xr-x    1 kazajhodo  admin     18 Jan  4 11:58 php@8.1 -> /usr/local/bin/php
```

If the version you want is there, you can link it with `brew link php@7.4`.

Then your bash should have php defined.

Installing php again will also work, because it will add the symlink in the install process; but you only likely actually need the symlink.

Comment: This is the one. I downloaded php@7.4 via brew without using a php formulae (see other responses). Using this I was able to locate and create a symlink. After that, 'php -v' works perfectly.

Comment: Works! Thank you. I used this command after downloading PHP view homebrew

Comment: I installed homebrew but don't have a /Celler folder in /usr/local

Answer (score 10):

I have same problem and this is the solution that I use for this.

1. install Xcode using your terminal

   ```
    xcode-select --install
   ```
2. install homebrew using your terminal

   ```
    /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
   ```

   when it finish the process you need to add the homebrew in your path and for this put this code

   ```
    echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/**xxxxxxx**/.zprofile
    eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
   ```

   **xxxxxxx** write your user name

   now you can check if homebrew is run correctly, use the next code.

   ```
    brew --version
   ```

   you can see in the terminal the version that you have install in your pc
3. now is time for install php for this

   ```
    brew install php
   ```

   finally, you can try see the version of php installed

   ```
    php --version
   ```

Answer (score 7):

If you want the latest PHP release in macOS Monterey then follow these steps:

1:  `brew tap shivammathur/php`

2:  `brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.2`

3: `brew link --overwrite --force php@8.2`

to check if its working, write this in the terminal: `php -v`

if you get something along the lines of **PHP 8.2.0-dev (cli)** then its working

Comment: i got this error  when I tried to run step 1. "Error: Failure while executing; `git clone https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/shivammathur/homebrew-php --origin=origin --template= --config core.fsmonitor=false` exited with 128.
"

Answer (score 3):

Just using  `brew install php` will install the latest php in mac.
You can then enable php in Apache by adding the following to httpd.conf and restart Apache:

`LoadModule php_module/usr/local/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so`

Answer (score 2):

You have to edit the file .zshrc

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

and Then you update the path for your php

type on "?" search "php" ... type enter, it will show you the line where php is. If not you have to add the path of your PHP.

You use Mamp, then it should on the root of mamp. set it on your .zshrc

This my .zshrc related to php :

```
#export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin:$PATH"
#export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/sbin:$PATH"
#export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"

export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@8.1/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@8.1/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t have a brew on your Mac. First, install the brew using the terminal. Enter the code below and hit enter

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

After installed brew

Type

```
php -v
```

to check the PHP version if PHP is not enabled it shows

```
zsh command not found php
```

The next step for checking the PHP is to enter the below command in the terminal

```
Sudo vi /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

After running completely check the blow line is shown in the listed line

#PHP was deprecated in macOS 11 and removed from macOS 12

If you find this line is shown or you don’t have php then enter the command below in the terminal

```
brew install php
```

If you already have PHP installed or run the above command successfully, enter the command in the terminal below.

```
brew services start php
```

Then it shows successfully started php.

Next, check the PHP version by entering the command in the terminal.

```
php -v
```

It shows the PHP version installed on your Mac

reference link : https://medium.com/@nadine.fisch/add-php-to-apache-on-macos-12-e3bb43469195

Comment: Command 
     brew link --overwrite php
helped me

Answer (score -2):

You probably need to fix it in the `.bashrc` file.

Do this:

Open the terminal and run this command:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Then add this line in the `.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/php/bin
```

Save and exit (`ctrl + x`)